# HtmlUnit seems to be ignoring setRedirectEnabled( false)

Tags: redirect, cookies, htmlunit

Or may be not, don't know what actually happens.
When I click on submit button within the login form on some site with usual mouse click in Chrome, I can see immediately in Chrome's network monitoring tool that 2 pages with the same address are being returned. One with 302 response code and "set-cookie" parameter, and other one with 200 code, and not containing "set-cookie". I need the first one - the "set-cookie" param contains the auth code. But when I use

```
      webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled( false);
      HtmlPage p = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage( wreq);
```

the onle page I get is the second one, with 200 response code and neither "set-cookie", nor the auth codes. So, is it just ignoring setRedirectEnabled(false), or the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: Can you please enable HttpClient wire logging and send the log to me. Will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i got you point - please try to provide more details about your problem.
HtmlUnit tries to simulate your browser; if you click on a button every real browser does the redirect for you behind the scenes. HtmlUnit does the same; the result of the click is the page you will see in the browser.
And like the real browsers HtmlUnit does the cookie handling. If you only like to address the cookie send by the first response you can have a look into the cookie store.

```
webClient.getCookieManager().getCookies();
webClient.getCookieManager().getCookie("the name of the cookie");
```

Regarding setRedirectEnabled(false):
Will have a look at this....